# Add ability to the Jython2.7 run JavaScript code

Tags: java, python-2.7, jar, burp, js2py

I am writing Python application as extension for Burp Suite app.
My application should parse JSON file which is a Postman collection, find all requests from collection and add it to the Burp site map. I successfully create script which parse requests themselves, its body and headers. But some requests contain pre-request scripts which is written using JavaScript.

Using default Python 2.7 I wrote such code with js2py library which allows to run JavaScript code using Python:

```
import js2py
class Postman:
    collectionVariables = []
    globals = []
    environment = []

    def run_pre_request_scripts(self, request):
        exec_script = self.get_exec_scripts(request)
        if exec_script is not None:
            js_code = self.reformat_script(exec_script)
            js_code = "pm = {'collectionVariables': [], 'globals': [], 'environment': []};\nvariable = {}\n" + js_code + "\npm;"

            pm = js2py.eval_js(js_code)

            self.collectionVariables.append(pm.collectionVariables)
            self.globals.append(pm.globals)
            self.environment.append(pm.environment)

    def reformat_script(self, str_list):
        formatted_script = []
        for s in str_list:
            if not s.strip():
                continue
            elif s.startswith(('var', 'const', 'let')):
                formatted_str = s.strip().replace('var', '').replace('const', '').replace('let', '').strip(" ")
                formatted_script.append(formatted_str)
            elif "pm.collectionVariables.set" in s:
                name = s.split("(")[1].split(",")[0].strip("'")
                value = s.split(",")[1].strip().strip(")")
                formatted_str = "pm.collectionVariables.push({'value': %s, 'key': '%s'});" % (value, name)
                formatted_script.append(formatted_str)
            elif "pm.globals.set" in s:
                variable_name = s.split("(")[1].split(",")[0].strip().strip('"')
                formatted_str = "pm.globals.push({'value': %s, 'key': '%s'});" % (variable_name, variable_name)
                formatted_script.append(formatted_str)
            elif "pm.environment.set" in s:
                variable_name = s.split("(")[1].split(",")[0].strip().strip('"')
                formatted_str = "pm.environment.push({'value': %s, 'key': '%s'});" % (variable_name, variable_name)
                formatted_script.append(formatted_str)
            else:
                formatted_script.append(s.strip())

        return '\n'.join(line for line in formatted_script if not line.startswith('//'))
```

Using this code I have ability to receive all variables from pre-request script like this:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set('today-1year','2020-01-18')
pm.collectionVariables.set('today-3year','2018-01-18')
pm.collectionVariables.set('today-5year','2016-01-18')
pm.collectionVariables.set('today-10year','2011-01-18')
pm.collectionVariables.set('today+5year','2026-01-18')

// generate random number between 1 and 10000
const number = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)*1);

// generate 'name'as unique value for the Party1

var CustomerName1 = "MPCustomer1" + number; 
pm.globals.set("CustomerName1", CustomerName1);

console.log("CustomerName1:", CustomerName1);


console.log("CustomerName1:", CustomerName1);
```

This code works fine locally using Python 2.7

My problem is, I need to run such code using Jython 2.7 which I upload as .jar file to the Burp Suite app. To run this code I need to add js2py library to .jar file because it does not contain js2py library itself.
I used such variants:

1. Run this commands to add library using pip

java -jar jython-standalone-2.7.3.jar -m pip ensurepip

java -jar jython-standalone-2.7.3.jar -m pip install js2py

But I got such error massage:

Collecting js2py
Using cached Js2Py-0.74.tar.gz (2.5 MB)
ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

2. I tried to add js2py library manually to the Jython jar file running this commands

jar xf jython-standalone-2.7.3.jar

cp -r  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/js2py Lib/

jar cfm jython-standalone-2.7.3-modified.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .

After these command in Lib folder will be placed js2py library. But if I will add this modified Jython .jar file to the Burp I will received such error:

AttributeError: 'tablecode' object has no attribute 'co_names'

And my python script will not start at all.

Give me an advice how can I add js2py library to the .jar file, or maybe send my such file with library already installed. Because I totally don't know what another variants I can used. I would understand if js2py library was allowed only for Python 3, but I used locally Python 2.7 and my code work without any problems. Thank you!

Comment: Jython and Python 2 are both outdated and deprecated technologies. And using an emulated language (Jython) to emulate a third language (JS) is a bad idea. Better directly include a JS runtime/engine into your Java project.

Comment: I should use Jython because I have working task to used it) You said it's better to include a JS runtime/engine into your Java project. Do you mean ScriptEngineManager engine? Can I include it to the Python project?

Comment: Fro my perspective Jython and Jython3 are dead. Using it for a new project is a very bad idea. Also try to avoid mixing languages/interpreting languages. That will only increase the effort for maintenance. Run each language in separate process/VM and communicate via network between them, e.g. using GRPC, JSON-RPC or something similar.

Comment: Truly saying I agree with you, that Jython is a bad idea. But problem is that Burp can run Python code only in Jython, that is why I should use it. You said I can separate Python and js precess, will it work in Burp app? Because js process must be working somewhere